# How to push data feed to Dashboard to be able create charts on it in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a basic dashboard.js which was on the Tutorial of React-admin.

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';

export default () => (
    <Card>
        <CardHeader title="Welcome to the administration" />
        <CardContent>Juhejj ez is mukodik!</CardContent>
    </Card>
);
```

Where can I find any documentation on how to push the data that's coming from my App.js < Resource > (from my Rest API) to dashboard?

I want to create Widgets, Charts onto my admin dashboard, but everything I've found so far was about creating a simple Dashboard with fake data in the dashboard.js.

```
const data = [{ bla: 1, bla2: 2 }];
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, mergeTranslations, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import { AdList } from './ads/AdsList';
import { AdEdit } from './ads/AdsEdit';
import { PostCreate } from './ads/posts';
import { LeadList } from './leads/leads';
import { UserList, UserShow, UserEdit, UserCreate } from './users/users';
import { ClickList, ClickMonthly, ClicksmonthlyList } from './clicks/clicks';
import PostIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Book';
import UserIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Group';
import Dashboard from './dashboard/Dashboard';
import authProvider from './authprovider/authProvider';
import jsonServerProvider from './dataprovider/rest';
import { reducer as tree } from 'ra-tree-ui-materialui';
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english';
import treeEnglishMessages from 'ra-tree-language-english';

const messages = {
    'en': mergeTranslations(englishMessages, treeEnglishMessages),
};

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://my.api.to/api/v1/');
const App = () => (
    <Admin dashboard={Dashboard} authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider} locale="en" messages={messages} customReducers={{ tree }}>
    {permissions => [
        <Resource name="ads" options={{ label: 'Hirdetések' }} list={AdList} edit={AdEdit} create={PostCreate} icon={PostIcon}/>,
        permissions === 'admin' ? <Resource name="users" options={{ label: 'Felhasználók' }} list={UserList} show={UserShow} edit={UserEdit} create={UserCreate} icon={UserIcon}/> : null,
        <Resource name="clicks" options={{ label: 'Legutóbbi kattintások' }} list={ClickList} />,
        <Resource name="clicksmonthly" options={{ label: 'Havi összesítés' }} list={ClicksmonthlyList} />,
        <Resource name="leads" options={{ label: 'Legutóbbi leadek' }} list={LeadList} />,
        <Resource name="sites" />

]}
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

One is doing it like in our official [demo](https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/) ([source](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/dashboard/Dashboard.js)), where we call the `dataProvider` directly, without using redux. You call it like you would for a classic fetch (maybe inside your `componentDidMount`). Something like:

```
dataProvider(GET_LIST, 'commands', {
    filter: { date_gte: aMonthAgo.toISOString() },
    sort: { field: 'date', order: 'DESC' },
    pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 50 },
})
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({ commands: response.data });
    });
```

The downside of this approach is that you'll have to handle errors, notifications, etc. by yourself.

The other way would be to use react-admin redux action creators to do the same thing but leveraging its side effects handling (notifications on errors, etc.). This time, you have to make your `<Dashboard>` a connected component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { crudGetList } from 'react-admin';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const commandState = state.admin.commands;

    // Is an object where keys are the commands identifiers
    // and the values are the command
    const commandsByIds = commandState.data;

    return {
        commands: Object.values(commandsByIds),
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    crudGetList,
}

const ConnectedDashboard = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

You would then call the `crudGetList` in your `componentDidMount` too:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.crudGetList(
        'commands', // resource name
        { page: 1, perPage: 50 }, // pagination
        { field: 'date', order: 'DESC' }, // sorting
        { date_gte: aMonthAgo.toISOString() } // filters
    );
}
```

**Final notes:**

We are aware the documentation could be improved for those use cases. The good news is that we are going to make it easier soon (probably in the `2.8` release): See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2899